# Does adding a DE to the contact builder data model automatically increase contact counts in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

If I am required to connect a data extension to the data model (for an outside product), does the contact count immediately go up before I am able to manipulate the data? The outside product has a different primary key than what we would use in SFMC and I do not want to duplicate contacts.

Example: Sendable DE connected with wrongid as primary key, connected to data model with 1:1 on wrongid=SFMC Contact Key

What I want to happen: Bring data in from other product, query to another DE with the rightid as primary key.  Then the Sendable DE is connected to data model with 1:1 on rightid=SFMC Contact Key

Answer (score 3):

No.

Sendable Data Extensions do not charge you Billable Contacts upon import or connection to the data model. You get charged at send time, because that is when the contact goes onto All Subscribers List using the key specified in the DE's Send relationship.

You'd have to purposefully make your DE a "population", then it would count. Judging from your usecase you have no reason to do so.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5